# In Java, when is an extension of a class at least as capable as the extended class?

Tags: java, android, oop, inheritance, class-design

My question is a little more complicated than what I was able to fit in the title.  And yet I'm not sure how to ask an appropriately-general question whose answer I would understand.  So I'll try to understand something more specific.

Suppose there is a public abstract class A.  And there is B, a direct public subclass of A.  Now the programmer needs to define a subclass C, and there is a question of whether C should be derived from B or derived directly from A.

B has some functionality that is absent from A and that will definitely be needed for the job at hand, and has nothing more than is needed.  But if C is derived directly from A, that functionality could be re-implemented in class C fairly easily, in about 6 or 8 simple little methods.  And of course  C will need some functionality that differs slightly from or goes beyond that of B.  Programmer Joe says that since stuff happens, there is as usual some chance of an error in the re-implementation of B's functionality, and why carry around the extra code, when B already has almost all of what is needed?  But programmer Bill makes a terse vague claim that deriving C from A gives "greater control" and greater possibility of optimization.  Joe notices that all of B's methods are needed for the application, and he shows that all but one or two can be used as-is, and he says that any of B's methods can be overridden in class C if needed, and any new methods that are needed can be defined as easily whether the derivation is direct or indirect.

Joe notices that A has only public methods and constructors and that none of them are final, and wants to claim that C derived from B offers just as much control as C derived directly from A.

Are there various conditions on the access-control properties of A and its methods and data members that would affect the answer?

If you need a concrete case embodying part of this question, consider A to be Android's BaseAdapter class and B to be Android's ArrayAdapter<> class.  I know that that very specific question has been answered on other threads.  But I would like to get at the essence of the access-control and other declared properties of the classes that would affect the outcome.

Comment: Since "greater control" has no meaning, the argument sounds like a waste of time. Reimplementing a lot of behavior that's already nicely packaged up also sounds like a waste of time, particularly absent any cogent reasons against it. I'm voting to close this as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: To add onto what Ted said, it highly depends on your design and how strict you are on design principles. You can usually tell whether or not a class should derive from another class by using the "is-a" philosophy, but other things such as the Liskov Subsitution Principle and Interface Segregation Principle play a role in this as well. In all, you should study deeper into inheritance principles, as that will help you decide what you should be doing.

Comment: It is not entirely opinion based... (at least in my opinion ;)  )    I think you are making a good example on why we have, use, and should learn design patterns. In the end it depends really on the situation... on whether you have to implement future classes that use functionality from base classes... One important thing in the end is always "favour composition over inheritance".    Other than that I can provide you with some patterns you should look into:  Template, Visitor, Composite

Comment: Well, I tried to motivate the question by giving an example that was somewhat specific relative to the built-in methods of A and B, and the needed functionality of C.  But please consider my question in an objective sense regarding whether either approach has more or fewer limits on the possibilities for implementing C and for extending C. My OO and Java experiences are not extensive, but it appears to me that they do not differ at all in that way.  If that is correct, then next I wonder what conditions on the access-controls or other properties, if any, would bring such a difference.

Comment: John, even if the question is interpreted as seeking objective (non-opinion-based) answers, I'd still vote to close it for being too broad (see [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) on this). I actually went back and forth on which reason to pick when I was voting to close. This is just not a good question for SO. You might have better luck on a forum like [Quora](http://www.quora.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems biased in that "Programmer Bill" is terse and his rebuttal is not given much merit or attention, while Joe's position is elaborate by comparison.

So to provide merit to Bill's comments about "control and optimization" - first, the counter argument for reusing code is that the use of existing methods that provide non-optimal functionality for specific cases is common and generally not a problem. However, it can be seen as sloppy and specific use cases may require re-implementation of existing methods in order to optimize them for specific purposes.

Doing this in the context of "extending Object B and overriding Object B's implementation of these methods" can easily be confusing or misleading to the original author later or programmers that later must maintain the code. Why inherit a class and it's methods only to override implementations specific to it? And further, why do so when the implementations it provided originally are useful elsewhere but not in this case? Inherit what you know is required, copy what you can to be time efficient and then customize for the specific case in front of you.

However, that is perfectly reasonable if the situation involves overriding a minimum number of Object B's methods and ideally for situations where B's methods are very simple or by their nature expected to be overridden, or there are a large number of methods that do not require re-implementation. In these cases it may be best to demonstrate this before discussing, so that Object B can be refactored to support inheritance and/or polymorphism better if needed.

What may be bad about this is that it may be a case of "premature optimization" on the part of both programmers - if the situation is untested, using Object B and then discovering the problems associated with that implementation is not much different from using Object A, copying Object B code and then performing optimizations that may be unnecessary or unneeded... both programmers appear to be speculating on the outcome without a firm basis for either argument or the expected performance problems/benefits. In which case neither has a firm position to progress the conversation or provide a firm recommendation based on the information given. But the information given is definitely biased in favor of Joe's observations, and disfavors Bill's brief account.

So the description of your question could lead a reader to think either A) programmer Joe is being lazy and trying to make a case for it or B) programmer Bill is letting his ego interfere with being practical. I tried to avoid either of these situations and address the real-world issue of programmers facing dilemmas that require being open-minded weighed against being short on time and resources, but feel free to comment accordingly.

Comment: This issue did arise for me in real life, and Bill's claims are just about as thin as I have presented, and he did not respond meaningfully to Joe's points, nor clarify his own, but seemingly tried to end it by saying that Joe could do it either way he wants.  If Joe gets an objective understanding of what can and cannot be done using the two approaches, he would finally conclude that by the nature of Java the indirect extension allows everything that the direct extension allows, and he would disregard Bill's vague claims and similar claims in the future.